# C++ Class - using public variables and defining member functions outside class

Tags: c++, class, oop

I have a defined a class C. I want to write all member functions in a file named C.cpp which I know how to. What I don't know is the following:

1. How to define one function, f, in the main? I tried:

   ```
   C::f(arguments){
   /*function definition*/}

   int main(){ /*code in main*/
   }
   ```
2. How to access and change a public member variable 'x' in my main after I define an object P of class C, without defining an explicit function for that? I'm looking to do something like

   ```
   P.x = 5.67;
   ```

Comment: Like ths: `P.x = 5.67;`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `1.`, If `f` is not declared in the class `C` (that is, in `C.h`), you cannot. you cannot `add` a function to a class *dynamically*.

Also if is is declared in `C.h` and also defined in `C.cpp`, then you are attempting to duplicate its definition, you cannot as well.

If it is declared in `C.h` and not defined in `C.cpp`, you can define it here in the main's file, BUT this is not recommended (bad practice). Better put all the class's definitions of methods in its `.cpp` file.

For 2, You can modify an attribute for an object of class `C` if that member was declared in the `public` section of the class:

```
class C {
... // private members
public: // public section
    double x;
    ... // other public members, methods or attributes
};
```

In this case you can, in main:

```
C P;
P.x = 5.67;
```

Comment: " cannot add a function to a class dynamically" Good word.  It is nice to stalk you.

Comment: Stackoverflow doesn't have it, so I can only save your name in a txt in my computer.   By the way, it's pity that you don't have provide information (web/mail) in your profile.

Comment: @javaLover That will change probably soon. (a little personal reasons atm).

Comment: Can I initialize variables in the header file itself? Does it have any severe repercussions?

Comment: @AnantJoshi Except constants, defining variables in header files in not recommended and yes it has serious repercussions. You can only declare them in the `.h` with the keyword `extern`, and define each of them only *once* in any of the `.cpp` files.

Comment: I meant initializing public variables of a class in the header file itself.

Comment: ah, yes you can do that (except for `static` class variables).

Comment: I declared a variable 'M' in the header file of class C as 

    `const int M = 1000;`

Then I initialized an array a

   `int a[M];`

error: invalid use of non-static data member 'C::M'

Comment: if a[M] is a static member or created in a static function of the class, its scope is per-member not per class. it is generally better to declate these constants as static constants. Try `static const int M = 1000;`. Or even better, `static constexpr int M = 1000;`. the keyword `constexpr` implies that the name refers to a *compile-time constant*. also note that when the static member is of type const or constexpr, you dont need later to *instantiate it* again in a cpp file.